# Android share button

Tags: android, share-button

After I've updated my question based on your responses, this is my .Class:

```
public class ShareScreen extends Activity{

         private ShareScreenAdapter adapter;
         private ViewPager viewPager;
         private String[] mThumbIds = Constants.IMAGES;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.share_screen);

             viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

             ImageButton sharingButton = new ImageButton(this);   
             sharingButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             sharingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.share);

             Intent i = getIntent();
             int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

             adapter = new ShareScreenAdapter(ShareScreen.this, mThumbIds);

             viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

             // displaying selected image first
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);   

     }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_share, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_share:
                    shareIt();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
             return true;

        }


        private void shareIt()
        {
            //sharing implementation here
            String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }


}
```

In menu/main_share.xml I have the share button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:title="Share"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:actionProviderClass=
                "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

Still not working ! The problem is that my shareButton from actionbar is not working. I click on it but nothing happen !

Comment: You have to associate this code with a view in your layout. Otherwise you are creating a button that share things, but the compiler won't know which button it is in your layout

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Post  logcat of when it crashes.

Comment: Do you want to show button in layout or actionbar?

Comment: @Harry, in action bar

Comment: @Rafael, very probably this is the problem, but I don't know how to exactly do that !

Comment: @ JonasCz, how do I save logcat ?

Comment: create menu item in menu.xml and call it onCreateOptionMenu or use [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

Comment: @Harry, I've already done that..

Comment: Then where is your optionItemSelected method? Or what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you wanto to do is the following

First, create `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`, which works for buttons clicked in `ActionBar`. Then, you fill code to match your objectives, like the following:

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_id, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.shareButton:
            shareit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
return true;
}
```

### Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"/> 
</menu>
```

Comment: it works ! Thank you  I m pretty new to android dev. !
Thank you one more time

Answer (score -1):

Hard to debug without the stack trace but from the code you have so far you've not actually added sharingButton to the view.

```
[view you want to add the button to].addView(sharingButton)
```